# Does React Native + iOS/Android environment provide a way to block undesired fetch (XSS/data exfiltration)?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, xss, content-security-policy

I'm currently developing both a mobile app and a web app with React Native and ReactJS frameworks. When developing in a JavaScript environment, you end up with hundreds (sometimes thousands) of npm packages and whether you agree or not, I consider all that third-party code unsafe when I handle sensitive data.

On the web app, I use strict CSP (Content Security Policy) rules when I serve my React App, and even if I do not rely all my security on that, I like it very much to have that extra layer of security.

I was wandering if there is some similar mechanism to block undesired fetching/networking in my React Native App.